# Good hash function for pair of primitive types

Tags: c++, hash

I'm trying to figure out a good hash function for a std::pair of two primitive types. This is the way I have it implemented right now:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<T,U> &rhs) const
{
    return stdext::hash_value<T>(rhs.first) ^ stdext::hash_value<U>(rhs.second);
}
```

It appears to work even if I have two pairs such as (1, 2) and (2, 1) (numbers flipped). They generate the same hash value but the values are still inserted successfully into the hash map. Any thoughts?

Comment: Generating the same hash from two different inputs is an expected occurrence, and any properly implemented hash table will handle it properly. But it might have an impact on the lookup speed.

Comment: You could use [`boost::hash_combine`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html) to combine the 2 hashes (or take a look at the source if you're not allowed to use boost)

Comment: You can try reversing the bits of the second hash.

Comment: Another problem with xor is that if the values of the pair are equal, the xor of the hashes will always be zero.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, hashing containers always have to handle this case (hash collisions). There are a couple methods they can use like chaining and probing, any of which will potentially hurt performance.

Instead, I would suggest using `boost::hash_combine` to combine the hashes in such a way they swapping `first` and `second` doesn't generate the same hash.

Comment: For more details about `boost::hash_combine`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation of `hash_combine` based on the docs from the current version of boost:
(http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine)

```
template<typename T> void hash_combine(size_t & seed, T const& v) {
  seed ^= stdext::hash_value(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<T,U> &rhs) const   {
  size_t retval = stdext::hash_value<T>(rhs.first);
  hash_combine(retval, rhs.second);
  return retval;
}
```

I can't actually vouch for the logic behind this function, but it looks more solid than most of the options mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that stdext::hash_value provides a good distribution of hash values for each of first and second, what you've done is fine if you don't expect a disproportionately high incidence of mirror image pairs (e.g. (1,2) and (2,1)).  If your data set is such that you *do* expect a lot of those, you might consider tweaking the hash function to force them to be different.  For example, inverting the first hash value:

```
return ~stdext::hash_value<T>(rhs.first) ^ stdext::hash_value<T>(rhs.second);
```

I mention this only because you expressed a concern about mirror image pairs.  If your input is close to random in that regard, then ^ should be fine.  Remember, the goal is to minimize collisions, not avoid them entirely.

Comment: Bad hash function. `~A ^ A` is the same (binary value of all ones) for all values of A.

Comment: Yes, but this is `~A ^ B`.

Comment: That said, I agree hash_combine is a better general-purpose approach.

Comment: @Mike: as well as the "mirror immage pairs" you address, as Michael says it's important to ensure `h(a, a) != h(b, b)` given different `a` and `b`

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, hash functions affect only the efficiency of hash tables, not correctness.  Your function is only bad if mirror image pairs are frequent. Since in some applications this might be a problem, it would be reasonable to swap upper and lower half-words of one hash value and then xor.  Many other schemes are possible, but this one is very fast and simple.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<T,U> &rhs) const
{
    const int h = sizeof(size_t) * 8 / 2;
    size_t a = stdext::hash_value<T>(rhs.first);
    return ((a << h) | (a >> h)) ^ stdext::hash_value<U>(rhs.second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, here's another approach that's simple and directly addresses the problem cases, specifically:

- if both `first` and `second` are the same, it returns their common hash value
- otherwise, it XORs the values but:

  - to prevent h(a, b) colliding with h(b, a), it uses a < b to choose between h(a)^h(b) and h(a)^h(~b)

Implementation:

```
1 template<typename T, typename U>
2 std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<T,U> &rhs) const
3 {
4     std::size_t a = stdext::hash_value<T>(rhs.first);
5     return rhs.first == rhs.second ? a :
6            a ^ (rhs.first < rhs.second ? stdext::hash_value<U>(rhs.second)
7                                        : stdext::hash_value<U>(~rhs.second));
8 }
```

Seriously though, I'd recommend following Mark B's advice and using boost::hash_combine - less branching is likely to improve speed.